# Alternative to doxygenfile for rendering file description with breathe

Tags: python-sphinx, doxygen

I have a project setup with doxygen + breathe for generating docs. I'm using the doxygenfile directive to display only the brief and detailed file description, like this:

```
.. doxygenfile:: DynamicArray.h
        :sections: briefdescription detaileddescription
```

I don't want the other sections, so after that, I go on to grouping functions under subheaders:

```
Lifecycle
---------
.. doxygenfunction:: DynamicArray_Create
.. doxygenfunction:: DynamicArray_CreateFromData
.. doxygenfunction:: DynamicArray_Destroy
```

However, every use of doxygenfunction causes a "Duplicate ID", "Duplicate explicit target name" and "Duplicate C declaration", pointing to the doxygenfile line. When that happens, the generated documentation for the functions does not have links. Removing doxygenfile fixes the problem.

This feels like a bug and I have created an [issue](https://github.com/michaeljones/breathe/issues/614). However, in the meantime, is there an alternate way to render the file description that doesn't use the doxygenfile directive?